# How to show visitor counter on footer of page using liferay?

Tags: liferay-6

I want to implement visitor counter on bottom of page and that page footer is configured through liferay 6.2 Kindly help me for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in Liferay that does this as well. You'll have to count for yourself and duplicate what all those services already do: De-Duplicate the requests that are coming in, determine if you want to count robots (determine if a visitor is a robot), determine if several users come from a single IP, determine if a single user comes from multiple IPs, reset the counter if you want to start over at the end of the day, etc etc etc.

Liferay has integrations with Google Analytics as well as Piwik (starting on 6.2). Other implementations are possible (easy actually), but remain for you to do them yourself. Be aware that the integration is easy while the implementation of the business layer might be harder.

Ref: https://web.liferay.com/pt/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/59503582